# What can cause Java to keep running after System.exit()?

Tags: java, exit, processbuilder

I have a Java program which is being started via `ProcessBuilder` from another Java program. 
`System.exit(0)` is called from the child program, but for some of our users (on Windows) the `java.exe` process associated with the child doesn't terminate. The child program has no shutdown hooks, nor does it have a `SecurityManager` which might stop `System.exit()` from terminating the VM. I can't reproduce the problem myself on Linux or Windows Vista. So far, the only reports of the problem come from two Windows XP users and one Vista user, using two different JREs (1.6.0_15 and 1.6.0_18), but they're able to reproduce the problem every time.

Can anyone suggest reasons why the JVM would fail to terminate after `System.exit()`, and then only on some machines?

**Edit 1:** I got the user to install the JDK so we could get a thread dump from the offending VM. What the user told me is that the VM process disappears from VisualVM as soon as he clicks on the 'Quit' item in my menu---but, according to Windows Task Manager, the process hasn't terminated, and no matter how long the user waits (minutes, hours), it never terminates.

**Edit 2:** I have confirmed now that `Process.waitFor()` in the parent program never returns for at least one of the users having the problem. So, to summarize: The child VM seems to be dead (VisualVM doesn't even see it) but the parent still sees the process as live and so does Windows.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> The parent process has one thread
>   dedicated to consuming each of the
>   child's STDOUT and STDERR (which
>   passes that output through to a log
>   file). So far as I can see, those are
>   working properly, since we're seeing
>   all the output we expect to see in the
>   log

i had a similar problem with my program not disappearing from task mgr when i was consuming the stdout/stderr. in my case, if I closed the stream that was listening before calling system.exit() then the javaw.exe hung around. strange, it wasn't writing to the stream...

the solution in my case was to simply flush the stream rather than close it before existing.  of course, you could always flush and then redirect back to stdout and stderr before exit.

Answer (score 20):

This can happen if your code (or a library you use) has a shutdown hook or a finalizer that doesn't finish cleanly.

A more vigorous (so should only be used in extreme cases!) way to force shutdown is by running:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().halt(0);
```

Answer (score 5):

**Check if there is a deadlock.**

For example,

```
Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread(this::close));
System.exit(1);
```

and in the `close()`

```
public void close() {
// some code
System.exit(1);
}
```

The `System.exit()` actually calls the shutdown hook and finalizers. So, if your shutdown hook calls the exit() again internally, for some reason (for example, when the `close()` raises an exception for which you want to exit the program, then you will call `exit()` there also). Like this..

```
public void close() {
  try {
  // some code that raises exception which requires to exit the program
  } catch(Exception exceptionWhichWhenOccurredShouldExitProgram) {
    log.error(exceptionWhichWhenOccurredShouldExitProgram);
    System.exit(1);
  }
}
```

*Though, it is a good practice to throw the exception, some may choose to log and exit.*

> Note, also, that `Ctrl+C` will also not work if there is a deadlock.
>   Since it also calls the shutdown hook.

Anyways, if it is the case, the problem can be solved by this workaround:

```
private static AtomicBoolean exitCalled=new AtomicBoolean();

    private static void exit(int status) {
        if(!exitCalled.get()) {
            exitCalled.set(true);
            System.exit(status);
        }
    }

    Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread(MyClass::close));
      exit(1);
    }

    private static void close() {
        exit(1);
    }
```

> P.S: I feel that the above `exit()` version must actually be written
>   in the `System.exit()` method only (may be some PR for JDK?) Because,
>   there is practically no point (at least from what I see) in
>   entertaining a deadlock in `System.exit()`

Answer (score 4):

Here are a couple of scenarios...

Per the definition of a Thread in http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html

...

When a Java Virtual Machine starts up, there is usually a single non-daemon thread (which typically calls the method named main of some designated class). The Java Virtual Machine continues to execute threads until either of the following occurs:

1) The exit method of class Runtime has been called and the security manager has permitted the exit operation to take place.
2) All threads that are not daemon threads have died, either by returning from the call to the run method or by throwing an exception that propagates beyond the run method.

Another possibility is if the method runFinalizersOnExit has been called. as per the documentation in http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/System.html
Deprecated. This method is inherently unsafe. It may result in finalizers being called on live objects while other threads are concurrently manipulating those objects, resulting in erratic behavior or deadlock.
Enable or disable finalization on exit; doing so specifies that the finalizers of all objects that have finalizers that have not yet been automatically invoked are to be run before the Java runtime exits. By default, finalization on exit is disabled.
If there is a security manager, its checkExit method is first called with 0 as its argument to ensure the exit is allowed. This could result in a SecurityException.

Comment: We don't have any calls to `runFinalizersOnExit`, nor do we have a `SecurityManager`, so I think these are not the cause.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a badly written finalizer?  A shutdown hook was my first thought when I read the subject line.  Speculation: would a thread that catches InterruptedException and keeps on running anyway hold up the exit process?

It seems to me that if the problem is reproducible, you should be able to attach to the JVM and get a thread list/stack trace that shows what is hung up.

Are you sure that the child is still really running and that it's not just an unreaped zombie process?

Comment: If it's a finalizer, then it's not one in our code---we don't have any. I'm sure the child is still running, since we see two Java processes and the user doesn't have any other programs on his system which use Java. I was kind of hoping to avoid asking him to install the JDK so we could use jstack, but I think now that might be the best way to proceed.

Comment: What I meant about the child process is, does it have any threads left?  Is it still responding to input?  Does it still have open handles?  I'm more familiar with Unix than Windows, but I know that processes aren't cleared from the Unix OS until the parent process reaps them and I think it's the same on Windows.  Just because it shows up in top or TaskManager doesn't mean it's still active.

Of course, that doesn't explain why it only happens to some users...

Comment: By default finalizers are not run on exit; see http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#runFinalizersOnExit(boolean)

Answer (score 1):

Does the parent process consumes the error- and outputstream from the child process?
If under some OS the childprocess print out some errors/warning on stdout/stderr and the parent process is not consuming the streams, the childprocess will block and not reach System.exit();

Comment: The parent process has one thread dedicated to consuming each of the child's STDOUT and STDERR (which passes that output through to a log file). So far as I can see, those are working properly, since we're seeing all the output we expect to see in the log.

Answer (score 1):

Hy i had the same problem, but the couse for me was i was using the remote Debugging(VmArgs: -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=%port%,server=y,suspend=y) when i disabled this the java.exe Process exited as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I think all of the obvious causes have been provisionally covered; e.g. finalizers, shutdown hooks, not correctly draining standard output / standard error in the parent process.  You now need more evidence to figure what is going on.

Suggestions:

1. Set up a Windows XP or Vista machine (or virtual), install the relevant JRE and your app, and try to reproduce the problem.  Once you can reproduce the problem, either attach a debugger or send the relevant signal to get a thread dump to standard error.
2. If you cannot reproduce the problem as above, get one of your users to take a thread dump, and forward you the log file.

Comment: I can't reproduce it myself on Vista, and the user can't get a thread dump from VisualVM, as the VM seems to be no longer alive.

Answer (score 0):

Another case not mentioned here is if the shutdown hooks hang on something so be careful in writing the shutdown hook code(and if a 3rd party library registered a shutdown hook that is hanging as well).

Dean