# JVM not shutting down after swing application exits

Tags: java, swing, jvm

I have a swing application with an exit button that calls a method which invokes System.exit(0); but the JVM doesn't shut down for some reason.  Does anyone know what could cause the JVM to continue running?

Comment: Do you have any non-daemon threads running at the time of exit?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What can cause Java to keep running after System.exit()?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2614774/what-can-cause-java-to-keep-running-after-system-exit)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Non-daemon threads will not keep the program from terminating when you call `System.exit()` (and daemon threads certainly won't) but shutdown hooks<sup>†</sup> will, if they fail to terminate.

<sup>† See [Design of the Shutdown Hooks API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/lang/hook-design.html) (the originally linked article is now only available at [the wayback machine](http://web.archive.org/web/20131026013125/http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/lang/hook-design.html)).</sup>

Swing probably uses shutdown hooks, but not in a way that would prevent your program from terminating. But if you (or some library you use) call [`Runtime.addShutdownHook()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#addShutdownHook%28java.lang.Thread%29), you'd better make sure your shutdown hooks don't deadlock.

By the way, one work-around for this problem is to make add a shutdown hook that spins off another thread that waits for sixty seconds, then calls [`Runtime.halt()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#halt%28int%29). (You have to spin off another thread because otherwise the shutdown hook, by waiting sixty seconds, will prevent the program from terminating for sixty seconds.)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you have a Thread that is still running?

It's quite easy to find which threads are running and when. In Netbeans, start your project in Profile mode (Alt+F2) to have a snapshot in real-time. (Profiler -> View ->Threads)

Comment: You can also use JVisualVM or its predecessor JConsole, both of which come with Sun's JVM. JConsole in particular has a handy "Detect Deadlock" button at the bottom of the Threads tab.

Comment: I didn't know about that "Detect Deadlock" button. Could be useful sometimes! Thanks!